Correcting numbering format for tables and figures
I am currently compiling a thesis consisting of three chapters. I want to use two-digit numbering for main tables and figures (1.1, 1.2, 2.1 etc.), and three-digit numbering for appendix tables and figures (1.A.1, 1.A.2, 2.A.1 etc.).
I have included the below code in the master document for the main tables and figures in the chapters:
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}

I have then used the below code for the appendices and it works fine.
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}
\numberwithin{table}{section} 
\numberwithin{figure}{section} 
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

My problem is to do with reverting back to 2-digit numbering in the next chapter. In particular, after I switch to 3-digit numbering for the appendix in chapter 2, the main tables and figures in the subsequent chapter also appear in three digits: for e.g. 3.3.1, 3.3.2 for chapter 3, whereas I want it to be displayed as 3.1, 3.2 etc.
I have tried several codes to renew the settings to 2-digit numbering at the start of chapter 3, but I haven't been able to fix the issue:
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
\numberwithin{table}{chapter} 
\numberwithin{figure}{chapter} 
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}

The above code fixes the issue to some extent, as in the tables go back to 3.1, 3.2 etc. within a subsection, but starts again at 3.1 for a new subsection in the same chapter. I want to achieve a continuous flow of table and figure numbering at the two-digit level within the chapter, spanning from 3.1, 3.2, ... to 3.7 for seven tables in the chapter.
Any coding help on how to fix this issue will be much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ. And, do please tell us how your document marks the transition from a "normal section" (w/ arabic numberals) to an "appendix section" (w/ uppercase letters).

Thank you for your response. I am using the 'report' document class. The code I mentioned above is what shifts the numbering from the main section to uppercase letters, i.e.  \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}. When I end the appendix with the \end{subappendices} command, the numbering reverts back to arabic numerals, however the digit-level remains at three instead of reverting back to two.

The fact that you're using a subappendices environment is information you hadn't disclosed so far. Where does \begin{subappendices} occur -- before or after \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}?

Apologies about this oversight. I use the following code at the end of chapter 2 before beginning the appendix: ```\begin{subappendices}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}
\numberwithin{table}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}```

When I remove the \numberwithin commands, the table numbering appears correctly in chapter 3, but the appendix tables don't appear properly. So I think I need a code to reset the \numberwithin after the end of chapter 2 appendix

Sorry, but my mind-reading skills have always been, and will always be, rubbish. What does "the appendix tables don't appear properly" refer to? Chapter 3 or chapter 2?

In chapter 2. The 3-digit numbering won't appear properly if I remove the \numberwithin commands. It will just continue as 2.8, 2.9 etc without 2.A.1, 2.A.2 etc. Is there a way to disable the \numberwithin after the appendices end at the end of chapter 2, before moving to chapter 3?

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

BTW: I would usually recommend to use the LaTeX kernel build in \counterwithin instead of the (old) amsmath command \numberwithin. But without MWE, I cannot say if this would even complicate the thing.

My apologies. Each chapter just includes the text, but the user packages and \begin{document}, \end{document} appear in the master file, and I use \include{chapters/Chapter1/chapter1} etc. to include the three chapters.

Some parts of your code are redundant as they duplicate the default settings of the report document class, while others are actually a bit too powerful (such as \numberwithin).
I suggest you include the following instructions in the preamble of your document:
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{appendix} % for 'subappendices' environment

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} 
\cftsetindents{figure}{0em}{3em} % extra space for figure and table numbers
\cftsetindents{table}{0em}{3em}

\AtBeginEnvironment{subappendices}{%
   \setcounter{table}{0}
   \setcounter{figure}{0}
   \setcounter{equation}{0}
   \renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesection.\arabic{table}}
   \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}
   \renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
}

That way, no extra markup will be necessary in the subappendices environments to affect the numbering style of table, figure, and equation objects.
Because the adjusted preamble loads the tocbibind package, I would also suggest that you simplify
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}

to just
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables


A compilable MWE (minimum working example):
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % automatically include LoF and LoT in ToC
\usepackage{appendix} % for 'subappendices' environment

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} 
\cftsetindents{figure}{0em}{3em} % extra whitespace for figure and table numbers
\cftsetindents{table}{0em}{3em}

\AtBeginEnvironment{subappendices}{%
   \setcounter{table}{0}
   \setcounter{figure}{0}
   \setcounter{equation}{0}
   \renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesection.\arabic{table}}
   \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}
   \renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables


\chapter{Uno}

\section{Uno-First}
\begin{table}[h!]\caption{Hello-Uno-First}\end{table}
\begin{figure}[h!]\caption{World-Uno-First}\end{figure}
\begin{equation} 1+1=2 \end{equation}

\section{Uno-Second}
\begin{table}[h!]\caption{Hello-Due-Second}\end{table}
\begin{figure}[h!]\caption{World-Due-Second}\end{figure}
\begin{equation} 2+2=4 \end{equation}


\begin{subappendices}
\section{Uno-Appendix}
\begin{table}[h!]\caption{Hello-UnoApp-First}\end{table}
\begin{figure}[h!]\caption{World-UnoApp-First}\end{figure}
\begin{table}[h!]\caption{Hello-UnoApp-Second}\end{table}
\begin{figure}[h!]\caption{World-UnoApp-Second}\end{figure}
\begin{equation} 3+3=6 \end{equation}
\begin{equation} 4+4=8 \end{equation}
\end{subappendices}



\chapter{Due}

\section{Due-First}
\begin{table}[h!]\caption{Hello-Due-First}\end{table}
\begin{figure}[h!]\caption{World-Due-First}\end{figure}
\begin{equation} 1+1=2 \end{equation}

\section{Due-Second}
\begin{table}[h!]\caption{Hello-Due-Second}\end{table}
\begin{figure}[h!]\caption{World-Due-Second}\end{figure}
\begin{equation} 1+1=2 \end{equation}

\begin{subappendices}
\section{Due-Appendix}
\begin{table}[h!]\caption{Hello-DueApp-First}\end{table}
\begin{figure}[h!]\caption{World-DueApp-First}\end{figure}
\begin{table}[h!]\caption{Hello-DueApp-Second}\end{table}
\begin{figure}[h!]\caption{World-DueApp-Second}\end{figure}
\begin{equation} 3+3=6 \end{equation}
\begin{equation} 4+4=8 \end{equation}
\end{subappendices}

\end{document}

